# Certain header elements not served over https

Tags: ssl

I have forced SSL on each page of my site using [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/). This works perfectly and isn't throwing up any mixed content warnings.

However, when I visit the page source, I can see a whole bunch of resources being served over http in the header. These are not resources that I control, but what I assume to be coming from the WordPress core. Here they are:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Website &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.example.com/feed/" />

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Website &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.example.com/comments/feed/" />

<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://www.example.com/wp-json/' />

<link rel='shortlink' href='http://www.example.com/' />

<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://www.example.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F" />

<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://www.example.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&#038;format=xml" />
```

What are these elements doing and should I be concerned that they are not being served over https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first one, the profile, but the `rel="alternate"`s and the `rel='shortlink'` provide different formats for different readers, like XML and RSS feeds. These should be generated by your site URL. In your dashboard, go to Settings > General, and make sure you're using https:// instead of http:// in the URL. You may then need to clear your site cache to see the change.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Changing the WordPress and site address URL causes a re-direct loop. Would it be better to do a search and replace on http:// instead?

Comment: Try adding `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` in wp-config.php, and install the WP Migrate DB plugin to migrate from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` - it will work a lot better than trying to manually search and replace. Some WP data is serialized and will be corrupted if you try updating it manually.

Comment: Annoyingly http://gmpg.org doesn't have a working https version..I am not sure what to suggest- perhaps ripping it out altogether?